# JQuery theme not loading properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, cordova, phonegap-build

here is the fiddle, the problem I am facing is, try to choose a theme from RIGHT SIDE PANEL (try to push the button on top right properly), change to theme B, and see the changes in LEFT SIDE PANEL, you wont see the theme effect initially, but when you hover over the buttons, the theme change happens.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
$('input[name=theme-options]').change(function() {
                var currentTheme = $('#content1').attr('data-theme');
                var currentThemeH = $('#headermaster').attr('data-theme');
                var currentThemeD = $('#demo-page').attr('data-theme');
                var currentThemeL = $('#left-panel').attr('data-theme');
                var currentThemeR = $('#right-panel').attr('data-theme');
                var selectedTheme = $(this).val();



            $('#content1').attr('data-theme', selectedTheme).removeClass('ui-body-' + currentTheme).addClass('ui-body-' + selectedTheme).trigger('create');
            $('#headermaster').attr('data-theme', selectedTheme).removeClass('ui-body-' + currentTheme).addClass('ui-body-' + selectedTheme).trigger('create');

                $('#left-panel').attr('data-theme', selectedTheme).removeClass('ui-body-' + currentTheme).addClass('ui-body-' + selectedTheme).trigger('create');

                $('#right-panel').attr('data-theme', selectedTheme).removeClass('ui-body-' + currentTheme).addClass('ui-body-' + selectedTheme).trigger('create');
                $('#link1').attr('data-theme', selectedTheme).removeClass('ui-body-' + currentTheme).addClass('ui-body-' + selectedTheme).trigger('create');
                $('#link2').attr('data-theme', selectedTheme).removeClass('ui-body-' + currentTheme).addClass('ui-body-' + selectedTheme).trigger('create');
                $('#link3').attr('data-theme', selectedTheme).removeClass('ui-body-' + currentTheme).addClass('ui-body-' + selectedTheme).trigger('create');
                $('#link4').attr('data-theme', selectedTheme).removeClass('ui-body-' + currentTheme).addClass('ui-body-' + selectedTheme).trigger('create');
                $('#link5').attr('data-theme', selectedTheme).removeClass('ui-body-' + currentTheme).addClass('ui-body-' + selectedTheme).trigger('create');
                $('#link6').attr('data-theme', selectedTheme).removeClass('ui-body-' + currentTheme).addClass('ui-body-' + selectedTheme).trigger('create');

            $("#demo-page").change();
            $("#left-panel").change();
            $("#right-panel").change(); 
            });
```

here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kWTXU/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this solves your issue:

```
$('input[name=theme-options]').change(function() {
            var currentTheme = $('#content1').attr('data-theme');
            var currentThemeH = $('#headermaster').attr('data-theme');
            var currentThemeD = $('#demo-page').attr('data-theme');
            var currentThemeL = $('#left-panel').attr('data-theme');
            var currentThemeR = $('#right-panel').attr('data-theme');
            var selectedTheme = $(this).val();              


        $('#content1').attr('data-theme', selectedTheme).removeClass('ui-body-' + currentTheme).addClass('ui-body-' + selectedTheme).change();
        $('#headermaster').attr('data-theme', selectedTheme).removeClass('ui-body-' + currentTheme).addClass('ui-body-' + selectedTheme).change();

            $('#left-panel').removeClass('ui-body-a ui-body-b ui-body-c ui-body-d ui-body-e').addClass('ui-body-' + selectedTheme).attr('data-theme', selectedTheme);

            $('#right-panel').attr('data-theme', selectedTheme).removeClass('ui-body-' + currentTheme).addClass('ui-body-' + selectedTheme).change();

Edit:
 $("#listpanel li").each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('ui-btn-up-' + currentTheme).addClass('ui-btn-up-' + selectedTheme);

                $(this).removeClass('ui-btn-down-' + currentTheme).addClass('ui-btn-down-' + selectedTheme);
        })

        $("#demo-page").change();
        $("#left-panel").change();
        $("#right-panel").change(); 
        });



    </script>


</body>
```

Comment: The theme selector on Right Panel also changes color, which shouldn't happen

Comment: this is the link to [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kWTXU/5/)
the THEME SELECTOR SHOULD MAINTAIN ITS COLOURS, is what I MEAN, It also changes according to the Changes we make